# How to get modified columns after columnmove() in Ext Grid with CheckBox Selection model

Tags: extjs, grid

I have a Ext Grid with CheckBox Selection model and I have made columns movable. Once I move the columns, I am not able to retrieve the columns' dataindex, how to get that ? I had cell modal and I was retrieving it perfectly with

```
var sm = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
        mode: 'SIMPLE',
        checkOnly: true,
        listeners: {
            selectionchange: function(sm, selected, eOpts) {
                listCB = selected;
                var gridID = Ext.getCmp('CiEditGrid');
                if(selected.length > 0){
                    gridID.getView().removeRowCls(0, 'hidden');
                    gridID.getView().addRowCls(0, 'custom-column1');
                    bEnableRow = true;
                }else{
                    gridID.getView().addRowCls(0, 'hidden');
                }
            },
            beforeselect: function(selModel, record, index) {
                var gridID = Ext.getCmp('CiEditGrid');
                popupIndex=index;
                colIndex=ColumnIndex;
                EditedValues.push({
                    colvalue:colIndex,
                    rowvalue:popupIndex
                });
                if (!((ColumnIndex == undefined || ColumnIndex == 0)))
                    return false;
            },
            beforedeselect: function(selModel, record, index) {
                if (!(ColumnIndex == undefined || ColumnIndex == 0))
                    return false;
            },
        }
    });
```

var CiGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {

```
store: mystore,
columns: datastore.columns,
selType: 'cellmodel',  
selModel: sm,
id:'CiEditGrid',
height: 775,
columnLines: true,
enableColumnHide:false, 
viewConfig: {
                forceFit: false,
                deferEmptyText: false,
                stripeRows: true,
                emptyText :'<div class="emptyTextClass">'+noRecordsFoundMsg+'</div>'
            },
lockedViewConfig: {
    emptyText: ''
},
listeners: {
    afterrender: function(grid, eOpts){
        var gridIndxArray = grid.columns;
        for(var i=0; i<gridIndxArray.length; i++){
            var Indx = i-1; 
            if(Indx == -1)
                Indx = 0;
            ColumnIndexArray.push({
                dataIndx:gridIndxArray[i].dataIndex,
                StoreIndx:Indx
            });
        }
    },
    columnmove: function(ct, column, fromIdx, toIdx, eOpts){
        isColumnreconfigured = true;
        fromCMIdx = fromIdx;
        toCMIdx = toIdx;
    },
    itemclick: function(data, record, item, index, e, eOpts){
        popupIndex = index;
        var position = data.getPositionByEvent(e);
        ColumnIndex = position.column;
        if(index == 0){
            multiCol.push({
                colIndex:ColumnIndex
            });
        }
        if(isColumnreconfigured){
            for(var i=0; i<ColumnIndexArray.length; i++){
                if(selModel.getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(colIndex).dataIndex == ColumnIndexArray[i].dataIndx){ //Not getting the value in selModel.getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(colIndex).dataIndex
                    colIndex = ColumnIndexArray[i].StoreIndx;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
},  
cls: 'custom-dirty', 
layout:'fit',  
border: false,
autoWidth:true,  
plugins: [cellEditing],
renderTo:'grid'
```

});

Not getting the values in "selModel.getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(colIndex).dataIndex"

Comment: What do you mean 'new columns'? Show your code and where exactly is your problem. Preferably with a working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#home).

Comment: New columns means, the columns after movement.

Comment: I don't see `colIndex` defined anywhere, also, if you need to access `selModel.getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(colIndex).dataIndex` in a loop, store it in a variable beforehand. Your code is really hard to orient in. If you just want to get a `dataIndex` of the moved column, you have the `colum` accessible right in your `columnmove` listener.

Comment: Actually I need to get dataIndex of each column after columnmove. In columnmove listener I am getting the from and to column Indices and I can then manipulate the entire columns but I am looking for a simpler solution. Like I used to get when I was using CellModel (selModel.getHeaderCt().getHeaderAtIndex(colIndex).dataIndex).

Comment: You can get an array of all grid columns with header container [`getGridColumns()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.header.Container-method-getGridColumns) method, you can use it like so: `var columns = selModel.getHeaderCt().getGridColumns()` and then iterate through `columns` in a `for` cycle.

Comment: Hello Marthy, thanks for help but 
for CheckBox selection Model, getHeaderCt() is undefined.

Comment: Sorry, not for CheckBox selection model, for grid. It should be like this: `var columns = grid.getView().getHeaderCt().getGridColumns()`

Comment: Thanks Marthy, It helped. I tried with grid.getView().getGridColumns() and it gave me all columns in new order.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the `dataIndex` of the moved column, you can do it in the `columnmove` listener, like so:

```
columnmove: function (ct, column, fromIndex, toIndex, eOpts) {
    var dataIndex = column.dataIndex;
    // ...
},
```

It's worth noting, that the `columnmove` event has `toIndex` argument, but it is the visible index of the column. To get the real index of the column, you can call [`column.getIndex()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-method-getIndex).

If you want to get all the columns after moving them, you can call the [`getGridColumns()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.header.Container-method-getGridColumns) method of the [grid header container](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.header.Container).

Having grid, you can get all columns like so:

```
var allColumns = grid.getView().getHeaderCt().getGridColumns();
```